# Does putting 2 parentheses allow me to pass 2 arguments when the function takes one?

Tags: python

I,m trying a BFS code where I need to append a node in a queue and increase it's level by 1. I used deque from collections. Here append
takes single argument as per the documentation. 
When I put a single parentheses and passed node and level increment,

```
queue.append(node.left,level+1)
```

it gave me the following error
`TypeError: append takes exactly one argument(2 were given)`.
However, when I put 2 parenthesis, `queue.append((node.left,level+1))` it worked fine. So does it mean the question?

Comment: By using two parentheses, you are sending a tuple (`(node.left, level+1)`) as the one argument.

Comment: You are not passing two arguments. You are passing a single tuple object as an argument, which happens to have two objects in it.

Answer (score 0):

Append takes exactly one parameter as stated by the interpreter itself but when you pass 2 values in a parenthesis python consider it a single argument which is tuple

Tuple is a collection of python object separated by commas

Answer (score 0):

When you use 2 parenthesis with an append() function, the interpreter takes it as a tuple, the append() only takes a maximum of 1 parameter.